# Find the sum of certain columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas to sum certain columns while retaining the others.
For eg:

```
member_no, data_1, data_2, data_3, dat_1, dat_2, other_1, other_2

1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0

1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1

2, 0, 1, 5, 1 ,0, 1, 0

2, 0, 1, 5, 1 ,0, 0, 1
```

I want the result to be

```
member_no, data_1, data_2, data_3, dat_1, dat_2, other_1, other_2  

1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1

2, 0, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1
```

For a given member id, all the columns with 'data' and 'dat' will have the same value and so I just want to retain that. The columns with the 'other' attribute needs to be summed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: one of your columns is missing values.

Comment: Your previous output was misleading. But now that you've fixed it, it's clear what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `groupby` on `member_no` + `max`.

```
df = df.groupby('member_no', as_index=False).max()
print(df)
   member_no  data_1  data_2  data_3  dat_1  dat_2  other_1  other_2
0          1       1       3       0      0      1        1        1
1          2       0       1       5      1      0        1        1
```

Comment: Almost but my member_no have all become 1.

Comment: I want to combine the 'other' attribute by each member_no

Comment: Could you give the equivalent of this for a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @Nivi No, I can’t, because I don’t know pyspark.